# javascript span click event - using google icon

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to do an event where the "span" tag is btn and the "main" tag disappears, but it doesn't work at all. Is using the Google icon a problem?
GenreBtn is an icon using Google icon.

```
let genreBtn = document.querySelector(".genreClick")
let mainBox = document.getElementsByTagName("main")

genreBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainBox.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML too.

Comment: `mainBox` is a collection

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querySelector(".main")

Html-

```
<span class="genreClick" type="button"> Btn </span>
<div class="main"> Hide this </div>
```

Javascript -

```
let genreBtn = document.querySelector(".genreClick")
let mainBox = document.querySelector(".main")

genreBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainBox.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: The correct selector would be `main` (without the dot, so not `.main`).

Comment: i know i used it for class selector

Comment: Since the OP is clearly using a `<main>` element (not a `<div class="main">`), your answer can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `mainBox` is HTML collection, not HTML element.
You can try like this:

```
let mainBox = document.querySelector('main')
```

Or

```
let mainBox = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]
// main tag must be exist, if there isn't main tage, [ mainBox.style.display = "none" ] will return error.
```